# Using MPI_Scatter and MPI_Gather to implement Master-Worker-Model

Tags: c, image-processing, parallel-processing, mpi, broadcast

I have written a MPI program for an image processing filter. The main goal of this program is that a given filter is applied to an image file using parallelized computations.

The MPI programm works fine and there are no issues.

Now I want to use the Master-Worker-Model for my MPI program.
After doing some research, I found out that MPI_Scatter and MPI_Gather are the commands I need.

But I don't quite see how they work. This is my first try to code it:

```c
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    // Filters

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    if(parent == MPI_COMM_NULL)
    {
        MPI_Scatter(); // What are the parameters?

        // Master reads in the image file and distribute it to the workers.
        MPI_File_open();
        MPI_File_read();
        MPI_File_close();
    }
    else
    {
        // After receiving data from the master, worker processes begin their job.

        /* Normally here would be the entire logic of this program.*/
        /* For simplicity I just skip it for readability.*/
        /* The calculcation is exclusively up to the workers.*/
    }

    // After finishing, the results will be sent back to the master.

    MPI_Gather(); // What are the parameters?

    MPI_Finalize(); 
    return 0; 
}
```

It won't be running because it's just a first prototype. What I want to know is whether I have understood the concept of the Master-Worker-Model.

Some feedback to the code would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From what I understood, `MPI_Comm_spawn` just creates multiple copies of same program and also established communication between them and returns an intercommunicator (probably some object to use to communicate with those copies) (used before `MPI_Scatter`?) `MPI_Barrier` is a blocking code which will block the processes until all processes have reached some specified point (called a specific function) (used before `MPI_Gather`?). I couldn't understand this one: `MPI_Intercomm_merge`. I can be wrong in my understanding though.

Comment: The [MPI standard document](https://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report.pdf) has an example of a manager-worker program (Section 10.3.5 - page 383). The example shows how a program, starting with only 1 process (the manager) can create/spawn another process (the worker) and interact with it. Once the worker process is created, the rest of the program would be the same as any other MPI program. You can easily extend that example to create multiple workers.

Comment: If your program only runs on one host (e.g. you're not doing distributed computing), I think multi-threading would be more suitable and easier solution to use for your problem.

Comment: MPI is very much not suitable for image processing. Especially if your image is only 1k pixels wide. Sending data around takes more time than most of the computations you’re doing.

Comment: @Aziz I became aware of this example. My problem is that there is no ```MPI_Scatter``` and ```MPI_Gather``` used for distributing data to the workers. Additionally, I was told that I had to use ```MPI_Intercomm_merge```. My MPI program is more complex than this example.

Comment: out of curiosity, why would you move from a parallel model (you claim you already have) to a master/slave model with only the master performing the I/O (which is typically less efficient than collective MPI-IO) ?

Comment: This is my current task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample program that shows how to perform the scatter/gather operations.
Note in your case, since the master task is not doing any work,  an inter communicator is the best fit (even if the semantic of collective operations on an inter communicator is not always very intuitive) and hence you do not need to `MPI_Intercomm_merge()`.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    MPI_Comm parent, intercomm;
    const int slaves = 2;
    bool master;
    int data[slaves];
    int mydata;
    int i, rank, root;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_get_parent(&parent);
    master = parent == MPI_COMM_NULL;

    if (master) {
        int errcodes[slaves];
        /* spawn the slaves */
        MPI_Comm_spawn(argv[0], MPI_ARGV_NULL, slaves, MPI_INFO_NULL, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &intercomm, errcodes);

        /* prepare data to be scattered to the slaves */
        for (i=0; i<slaves; i++) {
            data[i] = i;
        }

        /* here we assume there is only one master */
        root = MPI_ROOT;
    } else {
        intercomm = parent;
        root = 0;
    }

    /* scatter data from master to slaves */
    MPI_Scatter(data, 1, MPI_INT, &my-data, 1, MPI_INT, root, intercomm);

    if (!master) {
        /* slaves do their work */
        mydata = mydata + 1;
    }

    /* gather data from slaves to master */
    MPI_Gather(&mydata, 1, MPI_INT, data, 1, MPI_INT, root, intercomm);

    if (master) {
        int i;
        for (i=0; i<slaves; i++) {
            printf("Slave %d returned %d\n", i, data[i]);
        }
    }

    MPI_Comm_disconnect(&intercomm);

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That will help me to understand how everything works. The number of slaves is fix in your code. How would I perform it if the number of slaves would be user-defined?

Comment: that would not change much: do not hard code the number of slaves, but read it from the command line or a config file.

Comment: Ok, I will do that. Another thing is, that master process from parent group and the first slave process from slaves group have rank 0. This is not allowed. For this, I have to use MPI_Intercomm_merge(). Also only the master process chooses the filter to be used and sends it to the slaves. I think MPI_Bcast() is needed.

Comment: if you mean two tasks have rank 0 in the intercommunicator, then yes, two tasks have rank 0, but these tasks are in two different groups (this is how an intercommunicator work), and since data is scattered from master (e.g. rank 0 in group A) to all the slaves (e.g. ranks 0-3 in group B), then `MPI_Scatter()` in the intercommunicator is imho the best fit.

Comment: you can also `MPI_Bcast()` from master to slaves in the intercomm. `root=MPI_ROOT` on the master, and `root=0` on the slaves.

Comment: Is it possible to use ```MPI_Send``` and ```MPI_Receive``` instead of ```MPI_Scatter``` and ```MPI_Gather```? Can you show me an example how to rewrite it?

Comment: In an inter communicator, data is sent/received to/from the other group. So master `MPI_Send()` to ranks `0` up to `slaves-1`, and slaves receive from rank `0`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but can you show me it on your code? My programming skills are low.

Comment: What happens on stack overflow stays on stack overflow! Please do not contact me offsite unless I explicitly invite you to.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Sorry for doing this. You are the only one who pays attention to my problem. Yesterday I coded the entire Master-Worker Model from scratch and it is 95% done. It can be compiled successfully. If I run it, it will stuck. I guess there must be a deadlock everywhere.